# Java SWT shell window closing event

Tags: java, swt

I just have a quick question.

How do you override the window closing event for a shell in an swt application?
I want the X-Button to simple hide the shell, not close the program.

I tried something simple:

```
shell.addListener(SWT.Close, new Listener() {
      public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        shell.setVisible(false);
      }
    });
```

Still terminates the program.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could try

```
shell.addListener(SWT.Close, new Listener() {
      public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        event.doit = false;
      }
    });
```