# How to serialize a class when exiting the program

Tags: java, serialization

Maybe a stupid question, but I was wondering how I would go on when I want to serialize a class in java to a .ser file when the user uses the default close operation (x).

I know how to serialize, but I just can't seem to understand where I should put the code for the default close operation.

If that was not clear let me know and I will try to explain better!

Thanks a lot!

Sindre M

Comment: You can add a listener to the CLOSE event and then override the handle method to serialoze the object

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789202/java-swt-shell-window-closing-event. In this instead of doing the set visible, call the writeObject may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`WindowListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) is probably what you need. You can serialize the object in its [`windowClosing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing-java.awt.event.WindowEvent-) method.